# Parsing JSON Response Using Jackson Object Mapper with inner collection array of map

Tags: java, rest, jackson

I have a json response as below

```
{
  "event_date": "2014-10-10T19:18:04+05:30",
  "company": "b2c",
  "entity_id": 7,
  "attributes": {
    "id": 7,
    "order_id": 43,
    "status": "dispatched",
    **"quantities": [
      [{"idno1":2},{"idno2":4}]
    ]**
  }
}
```

here I don't have any clue  to covert this into java object because it has quantities with a key value pairs which will vary i.e.
key is idno1 for the first element and value is 2 and for the other key is idno2 and value is 4 so here both key value are varying and this is inside an array quantities which is again inside my json.

Please guide me how can I achieve this in java REST API using jackson API with ObjectMapper.

Many Thanks for your support!!!!

Comment: Are you _sure_ this is the json format? The quantities attribute looks extremely odd

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your quatities object have two square brackets `"quantities":[[{"idno1":2},{"idno2":4}]]`? Then this means its an array or array of map. Then you could create obejct like

```
class Attribute{
    int id;
    @JsonProperty("order_id")
    int orderId;
    String status;
    List<List<Map<String, Integer>>> quantities;
    //Getters & Setters 
}

class Event {
    @JsonProperty("event_date")
    Date eventDate;
    String company;
    @JsonProperty("entity_id")
    int entityId;
    Attribute attributes;
    //Getters & Setters 
}
```

Now for your json you could straight away parse like

```
String json = "{\"event_date\":\"2014-10-10T19:18:04+05:30\",\"company\":\"b2c\",\"entity_id\":7,\"attributes\":{\"id\":7,\"order_id\":43,\"status\":\"dispatched\",\"quantities\":[[{\"idno1\":2},{\"idno2\":4}]]}}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Event eventObj = mapper.readValue(json, Event.class);
System.out.println(eventObj);
```

If you dont want that extra bracket you can change your quantities object to `List<Map<String, Integer>> quantities` or even reduce to `Map<String, Integer> quantities`